# Pyspark, Add a character in the middle of a string

Tags: python, apache-spark, split, pyspark

Let's say I have a column of Strings like this

```
Hour
0045
2322
```

And I want it to become like this:

```
Hour
00:45
23:22
```

In order to after turn into a timestamp.
How would I go about it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace

df.withColumn("Hour", regexp_replace(col("Hour") ,  "(\\d{2})(\\d{2})" , "$1:$2" ) ).show()

+-----+
| hour|
+-----+
|00:45|
|00:50|
+-----+
```